# Trigger webhook from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, webhooks

Is there an easy way to trigger a webhook from a sharepoint online list?

My scenario is, I need a way to all end users to power on azure VMs.  I have a list of VMs and their resource groups in a sharepoint list.  I also have a runbook that can power on a VM, and just needs the vmname and resource group as parameter.  So what I need is a way for endusers to trigger the runbook and pass the vmname and resource group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps need to be done for configuring the web hooks,

1. Create the subscription for the particular list.

   a. Call the rest api https://YourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/lists('list-id')/subscriptions

   b. Pass the following header and data.

   ```
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Type: application/json

   {
    "resource": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('5C77031A-
     9621-4DFC-BB5D-57803A94E91D')",          

   "notificationUrl":"https://91e383a5.ngrok.io/api/webhook/handlerequest",
   "expirationDateTime": "2016-04-27T16:17:57+00:00"
   }
   ```

   "notificationUrl" given in the above is the API that gets called when event occurs.
2. Inside your API, make a call to /GetChanges API to get the changes.

Further read:

1. https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/webhooks/lists/create-subscription
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetChanges